# Can I use the Spring Framework for non web applications?

Tags: spring

I'd like to use the Spring Framework for desktop applications.
Is it possible? What tools would complement the development(Roo, STS, etc...)?

Comment: normally the approach should be other way around, these are my requirements like IoC, can spring do it ? Rather than thinking what components of spring i can fit in my desktop application.

Comment: See [How can I use Java Spring Framework for non-web applications?](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-use-Java-Spring-Framework-for-non-web-applications)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes Mate. Spring has best features to use with Desktop applications too, like Dependecy Injection, Transaction Management, Spring ORM, Spring Batch etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Dependency Injection framework Spring is based on is a general-purpose thing. You can use it wherever you intend to use DI.